# UWP C# FullTrustProcess

Tags: c#, uwp

I'm new to UWP app and after 2 days of research I come to you…
I'm trying to run an executable from an uwp app so I looked at FullTrustProcess.
I added "Windows Desktop Extension for the UWP" to my references, my exe is in "Assets" folder and my manifest looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Package
  xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10"
  xmlns:mp="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/phone/manifest"
  xmlns:uap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/uap/windows10"
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap desktop">

  <Identity
    Name="22c57925-bd2a-4ebf-97e9-7a860ef17b3c"
    Publisher="CN=charl"
    Version="1.0.0.0" />

  <mp:PhoneIdentity PhoneProductId="22c57925-bd2a-4ebf-97e9-7a860ef17b3c" PhonePublisherId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000"/>

  <Properties>
    <DisplayName>CustomCortanaCommands</DisplayName>
    <PublisherDisplayName>charl</PublisherDisplayName>
    <Logo>Assets\StoreLogo.png</Logo>
  </Properties>

  <Dependencies>
    <TargetDeviceFamily Name="Windows.Desktop" MinVersion="10.0.14393.0" MaxVersionTested="10.0.14393.0" />
  </Dependencies>

  <Resources>
    <Resource Language="x-generate"/>
  </Resources>

  <Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
  </Capabilities>

  <Applications>
    <Application Id="App"
      Executable="$targetnametoken$.exe"
      EntryPoint="CustomCortanaCommands.App">
      <uap:VisualElements
        DisplayName="CustomCortanaCommands"
        Square150x150Logo="Assets\Square150x150Logo.png"
        Square44x44Logo="Assets\Square44x44Logo.png"
        Description="CustomCortanaCommands"
        BackgroundColor="transparent">
        <uap:DefaultTile Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Wide310x150Logo.png"/>
        <uap:SplashScreen Image="Assets\SplashScreen.png" />
      </uap:VisualElements>

      <Extensions>
        <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\shutdown.exe">
          <desktop:FullTrustProcess>
            <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="SyncGroup" Parameters="/Sync"/>
            <desktop:ParameterGroup GroupId="OtherGroup" Parameters="/Other"/>
          </desktop:FullTrustProcess>
        </desktop:Extension>

      </Extensions>

    </Application>
  </Applications>
</Package>
```

Visual Studio keep telling me that this command does not exist in the current namespace

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

What i'm doing wrong ?? Please help me, it's frustrating to try to run an exe for 2 days...

Comment: The manifest doesn't matter yet, you need to get it compiled first.  From the MSDN docs: "(introduced v10.0.14393.0)".  Remove the "Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP" reference from the References node of your project and add it back.  Pick the right version, at least 14393

Comment: I tried but the most recent version I have is the 10586.
How can I have the latest versions? I installed all the uwp sdk available but without success

Comment: Okay i changed the version target in the project properties and it appear and works.
Thanks !